# Google API gives login error when adding member to a group using admin sdk api

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-admin-sdk

I am using Simple Http request of google api to add a member in a group

I had set up a new project in my google admin console and have a key, clientid, client secret, service account name and after that I write this code to add a member to a group. But it gives me error. Can anyone suggest where I am doing wrong

```
    include_once __DIR__ . '/GoogleClientApi/vendor/autoload.php';
    include_once __DIR__. '/GoogleClientApi/src/Google/Auth/Google_AssertionCredentials.php';

    $clientId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxc7iqi.apps.googleusercontent.com';

    -----------------------------------
       -----------------------------------

    $scopes = array(
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user'
    );

    ------------------------------
------------------------------------------

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName($appName);
    $client->setClientId($clientId);
    $client->setAssertionCredentials($creds); // This line gives the error
```

This code gives me following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Google_Client::setAssertionCredentials().
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you exactly what the problem is.

```
Login required
```

In order to access private data such as adding users to your admin account you need to be authenticated first.

If you check the top of the documentation page for that method [Members: insert](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/insert) you will notice that it states.

> Requires [authorization](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/insert#auth)

I don't know what language you are using as you haven't posted any code but a good place to start would be to check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/authorizing)

Comment: I had done a bit search and found code for adding member to a group. But It now gives this error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Google_Client::setAssertionCredentials(). Please see my updated question

Comment: You should created a second question this isn't part of the first question.